# difference of the values of a function is an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a very simple quesiton but something I don't understand. From Taylor expansion: $$f(y)-f(x)=f'(x)(y-x)+O((y-x)^2)$$
so, if I just picture that, on the left is the difference between two values of the function and on the right hand side, this is basically a triangle, a measure of the area. To make things simple, assume f is a linear function $f(x)=x$, so I have 
$$f(y)-f(x)=f'(x)(y-x)$$
Now, I introduce another function $F(x)$, that is the measure of the area under the function f, then
$$F(y)-F(x)=F(y)=f(y)-f(x)$$
and in particular if $x=0$ I end up with $$F(y)=f(y)-f(x=0)=f(y)$$
and therefore have $$F(y)=f(y)?$$
So, there is a mistake somewhere. I guess I interpreat the area under a function wrong but I can't make a solid statement in this case how the difference between two points and the area under the function are related. Please help.